# How do you call this relation between 2 .c files?

Tags: c++, c, makefile, uml

I'm a bit confused, I haven't been doing C since years and I'm starting with it right again. One thing I'm not clearly sure is the relation of two files that call each others function, example:

> *testa.c*:

```
int main (void)
{
    callTheOtherFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

and the other file

> *testb.c*

```
callTheOtherFunction(){
//do some stuff
}
```

now my "makefile" looks like

> gcc -o test ./testa.c ./testb.c

What does it mean? Is `callTheOtherFunction` now part of testa.c, like both files have been merged? Or has it something to do with inheritance ? Is `callTheOtherFunction` now a global function, or how would you call it?

I need to draw an UML diagram out of it, that's why I need the expression for that case.

Comment: The two source files are compiled into *object code* and then these two *object files* are linked together with *system libraries* to make an *executable*.

Comment: This might help: http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Compiling-multiple-files.html

Comment: noooo don't remove my tags :). I was thinking about how to draw a UML diagram out of it, that's why I need to know how you call this kind of `call` methods

Comment: They would be two different [_translation units_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)), which are compiled into objects files and then linked together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source files are never "merged". What happens is that during compilation phase two object files will be produced - one for each source file and later during linking phase the two object files will be linked(and also linked with some implicit system libraries) producing an executable.

Comment: but why does the exe work ? I mean I don't have any reference in the sourcecode to the other file, but the program is able to figure out that this function belongs to `testb.c`. The only reference I do, is in the makefile, this is confusing

Comment: @user3085931 the linker will look into the object files being linked, find the implementation of the function being called and link the call to the implementation

Comment: ah... so this is somehow like a macro ?

Comment: @user3085931 macros are expanded in the beginning of the compiler phase i.e. much earlier. I am not sure what you mean by "like a macro". One thing that may help you is the fact that if the linker can not find an implementation for a given function or finds more than one definition in all generated object files, it will fail with an error. Try implementing main in both files for instance and you will see.

Comment: @user3085931: To say it simple: The compiler compiles each file separately to "final" processor intructions. If there is a function X used in file Y but not implemented there, it will generate  "call func X, and X is at address ???". The linker gets all precompiled files, merges them to one exe and fills in all missing ??? contents

Answer (score 2):

The two files will be compiled to object code by your compiler, then the linker will generate a single executable from the object files. It is, as you say, *like* the two files have been merged.

`callTheOtherFunction` will be accessible from anywhere (I suppose you would call that a global function) as you did not mark its definition `static`.

As a side note, you should probably get a compiler warning from that compilation as you do not have a declaration of `callTheOtherFunction` in *testa.c*.